# IndexedDB IDBKeyRange availability in amp-script

Tags: amp-html, indexeddb, web-worker

I have a custom script that is using browser storages such as IndexedDB or LocalStorage.

I'm trying to use it within AMP page but getting `ReferenceError: IDBKeyRange is not defined`

```
<amp-script width="50" height="50" script="my-custom-script"></amp-script>
<script id="my-custom-script" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
  // script body goes here
</script>
```

I know `amp-script` makes script run in WebWorker, but I haven't found any restrictions to use `IDBKeyRange` there.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using a supported AMP/JS component?

Comment: Hi @JayGray, sorry, not sure what do you mean. I'm using amp-script to import my custom JS, custom JS wasn't adapted to be used in AMP but I'm not even sure that it should be adapted and in what fashion

Comment: You need a security hash in head (https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) and your can only use these APIs (https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/main/web_compat_table.md)